# How to:Test-drive ASP.NET WebForms development?

Tags: asp.net, tdd

How do you test-drive ASP.NET WebForms development in VS08?

Comment: Do you mean the whole solution (UI,Domain,DAL et. al) or just the WebForms project?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must very well undrestand of MVP (Model, View, Presenter) pattern. This one will allow you to separate your logic from WebForms page, and page itself would be implementing View interface.

Here I quicly found that people are implemented a framework for that, that might be usable:

http://webformsmvp.com/

Long time ago I blogged about it, but in russian.. Hope some code samples might work for you:

http://www.beletsky.net/2010/04/web-development.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about simulating user input you could use Watin or Selenium. I'm sure there are other frameworks, but those are the 2 I know about.

I'd go for selenium if you're using telerik controls, as that's what they use to test the actual controls.

Comment: Will these tools even test a grid of data used for CRUD?